# Select unique column based on a particular column; condense

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Selecting Unique invoices only.

I have the following Table:

```
Invoice Date    Invoice No  Description                     PO No           Order No            Amount  Credit  Total
2013-04-26      T641913   PURCH/GRIP/SHOWCARD               LG5582          T196786             314.25      0   314.25
2013-04-26      T641914   PURCH/GRIP/SASH & TAPE            LG5593          T196855             251.20      0   251.20
2013-04-26      T641915   PURCH/LTG/BULB & RECEIVERS        LG5595          T196858             202.59      0   202.59
2013-04-26      T641916   PURCH/GRIP/STYRO & SILENT GRID    LG 5599         T196888             257.81      0   257.81
2013-04-26      T641      MAIN HEAD                         LG 5580         T192282             147725.62   0   147725.62
2013-04-26      T641      MAIN HEAD                         LG 5649         T196707             147725.62   0   147725.62
2013-04-26      T641      MAIN HEAD                         LG 5580         T192279             147725.62   0   147725.62
2013-04-26      T641      MAIN HEAD                         LG 5580         T192280             147725.62   0   147725.62
```

I need to condense and only select by the Unique Invoice#. The resulting table should look like the following:

```
Invoice Date    Invoice No  Description                     PO No           Order No            Amount  Credit  Total
2013-04-26      T641913   PURCH/GRIP/SHOWCARD               LG5582          T196786             314.25      0   314.25
2013-04-26      T641914   PURCH/GRIP/SASH & TAPE            LG5593          T196855             251.20      0   251.20
2013-04-26      T641915   PURCH/LTG/BULB & RECEIVERS        LG5595          T196858             202.59      0   202.59
2013-04-26      T641916   PURCH/GRIP/STYRO & SILENT GRID    LG 5599         T196888             257.81      0   257.81
2013-04-26      T641      MAIN HEAD                         MULTI           MULTI               147725.62   0   147725.62
```

Not sure how to do this:S Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [Invoice Date],
  [Invoice No],
  Description,
  [PO No] = CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 1 THEN 'MULTI' ELSE MAX([PO No]) END,
  [Order No] = CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 1 THEN 'MULTI' ELSE MAX([Order No]) END,
  Amount,
  Credit,
  Total
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY [Invoice Date],
  [Invoice No],
  Description,
  Amount,
  Credit,
  Total
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/606ba/2).

Comment: +1: I answered the question too, but this does the same thing and is more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CTE answer...

```
With    cte As
(
        Select  Count(1) As i, 
                [Invoice No],
                'MULTI' As val
        From    [Table]
        Group   By [Invoice No]
        Having  Count(1) > 1
)
Select  Distinct
        t.[Invoice Date],
        t.[Invoice No],
        t.[Description],
        IsNull(c.val,t.[PO No]) As [PO No],
        IsNull(c.val,t.[Order No]) As [Order No],
        t.[Amount],
        t.[Credit],
        t.[Total]
From    [Table] t
Left    Join cte c
        On  t.[Invoice No] = c.[Invoice No]
```